# 'find' with 'xargs'

Tags: shell, find, xargs

Consider:

```
cat fileNames.txt | xargs find . -name
```

I expect the above command to find the path of every file name in fileNames.txt, but this command produces no output. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution would be:

```
 xargs --max-args=1 find . -iname < fileNames.txt
```

Comment: If `fileNames.txt` contains one file name (or rather pattern) per line (as opposed to file names quoted properly for `xargs`), use `xargs -d '\n'`.

Comment: @Gilles: For `xargs` that supports it, I would use `xargs --arg-file fileNames.txt ...` instead of the redirection.

Answer (score 3):

A regular `xargs` call removes the newline characters, putting all the lines from the input in a single command line. You can however use the `-I <pattern>` option, where a command will be called for each line of input, with `<pattern>` replaced with line contents.

Note also, that you should probably add the `-print` option to have the paths listed.

```
cat fileNames.txt | xargs -I {} find . -name {} -print
```

Comment: what I don't get is why do we need curly braces after -I?

Comment: this is a "pattern", which will be searched (and found after -name) to show the place where a filename from fileNames.txt should be inserted

Comment: @dta: You could just as easily use `xargs -I % ... -name % ...`

Answer (score 1):

The `-name` option takes just a single argument.  I'm not sure why you're not getting an error message.  Try

```
sed 's/.*/-name "&"/' fileNames.txt | xargs find .
```

Comment: A single quote is missing after sed. So the correct version is : sed 's/.*/-name "&"/' fileNames.txt | xargs find .

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far have a hard time with filenames containing space, ' or ":

```
$ echo \'\ \" |  xargs -I {} find . -name {} -print
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

$ echo \'\ \" | sed 's/.*/-name "&"/' | xargs find .
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
find: missing argument to `-name'
```

If the files are made by users, you *will* experience funny named files. If you have GNU Parallel installed you can do:

```
cat fileNames.txt | parallel find . -name {} -print
```

Watch the intro video to learn more about GNU Parallel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

GNU Parallel can be downloaded at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/ and has been reported to be working under Cygwin.

Comment: Actually, [akavel's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/210946/find-with-xargs/210958#210958) is correct in that respect, as `-I` disables input quoting. (And to nitpick, [reinierpost's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/210946/find-with-xargs/210955#210955) deals with `'` correctly, but fails on `"`.)

Comment: how do I get parallel for Cygwin? which package does it belong to?